# How can I parse RDF data into model? (java, jena)

Tags: xml, parsing, rdf, jena

I'm trying to parse RDF data and load it to a model instance. However, I don't want to read the data from a file, but rather get it through an URI via http get.

What I did untik now ist this:

```
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read(rdfdata, null);
    model.write(System.out);
```

rdfdata is the data that I received (String). But I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotNotFoundException: Not found: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> [...]
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it? 
Is it right to just read the data into the model or do I have to do something before? 
Sorry for my bad english. :)

Answer (score 1):

The model.read() method takes a URL directly. Instead of reading the data into a string just pass the URL directly to it. To the second argument either pass null or "RDF/XML".

Look at the documentation here. 
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says:

```
Not found: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> [...]
```

Staring at that, it *appears* that it's reporting that the file or URI named `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>...` can't be opened.  Which makes sense, since that's unlikely to be a correct file name.

Check the documentation of `model.read()`, and in particular check what its first argument is.  Also check what `rdfdata` is: is it the path to a file or a URI? (it looks like it's the *contents* of an RDF/XML file).

(If this guess is right, then) Moral of the story: recall that when writing an error message, a programmer is typically at least *trying* to be helpful, thus ‘what is this gibberish^Werror message trying to tell me?’

Comment: read(String url). I dont see where to problem is, since I give it a String. And yes, it is a rdf/xml file.

Comment: Ok, I now changed my code that I save the url content in a file first and then read from it. Thank you!

Comment: On looking at the documentation for [Model.read(String,String)](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) it looks like my guess was wrong, and that the first argument is indeed supposed to be the URL. In other words no, I now can't see anything obviously wrong. Hmm: however hard the programmer was trying, that's really not a helpful error message...  If you've changed your code to make this work, you might want to answer your own question.